# I am doing the program the subtracting game (NIM) in one of my exercises its asking me for another loop around the main loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
// Exercise2.5.3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Revising of the program so that it keeps playing the game until the    user wants to quit.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

char ans;
char stop;
do
{
    int total, n;
    cout << "Welcome to NIM. Pick a starting total: ";
    cin >> total;
    while (total < 1){
        cout << "Enter positive integer only. ";
        cout << "Pick starting total: ";
        cin >> total;
    }

while (true) {

        // Pick best reponse and print results.

        if ((total % 3) == 2) {
            total = total - 2;
            cout << "I am subtracting 2. " << endl;
        }
        else {
            total--;
            cout << "I am subtracting 1." << endl;
        }
        cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
        if (total == 0){
            cout << "I win!" << endl;
            break;
        }

// Get user's response; must be 1 or 2.

        cout << "Enter num to subtract (1 or 2): ";
        cin >> n;
        while (n < 1 || n > 2) {
            cout << "Input must be 1 or 2." << endl;
            cout << "Re-enter: " << endl;
            cin >> n;
        }
        total = total - n;
        cout << "New total is " << total << endl;
        if (total == 0) {
            cout << "You win!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)?\n";
    cout << "You must type a 'Y' or an 'N'.\n";
    cin >> ans;
} while ((ans != 'Y') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n') && (stop != "0"));








return 0;
```

}

1. It gives a error after I run / compile the code  1   IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("char" and "const char *")
2. Do I have to use a do while loop or a while loop around my main loop in order for the program to work correctly and executes exactly what is asking ?? so that the program keeps playing the game until the user wants to quit ??
3. This is the program I try with the do while loop but is not working correctly exactly how it wants to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare:

```
char stop;
```

then use a `"0"` here:

```
} while ((ans != 'Y') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n') && (stop != "0"));
```

Try `'0'` because:

`"0"` is a `const char *`

`'0'` is a `const char`

Or since you never use `stop`, just remove it:

```
} while ((ans != 'Y') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n'));
```

Comment: I edit my code with  } while ((ans != 'Y') && (ans != 'N') && (ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n')); but when I run the program once I finish it asks me do you want to continue (Y/N) ? You must type a 'Y' or an 'N'. When I type in Y it gives me press any key to continue. I press enter and then it puts me out of the console. I think it should lead me back to the start of the game ?

Comment: you should try to fix that yourself, the hint is you need another loop to verify input and the main loop should be for `y` or `Y`.   This fixes your compiling so you can use the debugger

Comment: so instead of int total, n; I put int total, y; ??

Comment: I have no clue how to make the main loop for y or Y.

Comment: I guess the program dose not have to go back to the begging after putting Y for continue it only has to be there.

Comment: I don't know how  the debugger works yet can you tell me any other way to fix this problem ?? Because I have a strong feeling that the program actually has to execute back and starts playing again after you hit Y. But it did help me to to stop the problem with  1 IntelliSense: operand types are incompatible ("char" and "const char *")

Comment: I already found the answer from another questions asked here.